# Ionic 2 - Navigation between pages with parameters (blank app)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a blank ionic 2 project and there is a page with a list. When you click on a list item you should see the detail view of the item. Here are my list files:

list.html:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>list</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="list">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewItem(item)">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

list.js:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ItemDetailPage} from '../item-detail/item-detail';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/list/list.html',
})
export class ListPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(nav) {
      this.nav = nav;

      this.items = [
          {title: 'Hi1', description: 'whats up?'},
          {title: 'Hi2', description: 'whats up?'},
          {title: 'Hi3', description: 'whats up?'}
      ];
  }

  viewItem(){
      this.nav.push(ItemDetailPage, {
          item: item
      });
  }
}
```

And here are my detail view files:

detail-view.html:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="item-detail">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            {{description}}
        </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>  
</ion-content>
```

detail-view.js:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/item-detail/item-detail.html',
})
export class ItemDetailPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
      this.navParams = navParams;

      this.title = this.navParams.get('item').title;
      this.description = this.navParams.get('item').description;
  }
}
```

When I use "ionic serve" I get the following message:

> SyntaxError: C:/.../app/pages/item-detail/item-detail.js: Unexpected token (18:23) while parsing file: ...

So I think the constructor of the detail view dont work this way. But I found nowhere something what could help me. I think this solution is deprecated because the tutorial I found is from 2015. But like I said, I didnt found something usefull about it. My Ionic Framework Version is 2.0.0-beta.8

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
(click)="viewItem(item)"
```

You're sending the item as parameter, but in the method:

```
viewItem(){
  this.nav.push(ItemDetailPage, {
      item: item
  });
}
```

You are not getting it. I think you just need to include it as a parameter like this and it should work fine:

```
viewItem(item: any) {
  this.nav.push(ItemDetailPage, {
      item: item
  })
}
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot that. But I still get same syntax error on the constructor of detail-view.js

Comment: You can also check [this amazing tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-first-look-series-your-first-ionic-2-app-explained/) to see how this master-detail workflow should be done.

Comment: And maybe this [starting project for Ionic with side menu navigation](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-sidemenu) could help you too.